# OpenXML: How to modify an excel's cell attribute?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Given the following XML tag:

```
<x:c r="C1" s="9"/>
```

Using OpenXMLReader, I would like to access cell `C1` and modify the xml attribute to add a new datatype `t="inlineStr"` which would then allow me to insert a text to the cell as follows:

```
<x:c r="C1" s="9" t="inlineStr"/> 
  <x:is>
       <x:t>Report Title</x:t>
  </x:is>
```

This is my code which accessrd the cell:

```
if (oXMLReader.ElementType == typeof(Cell))
{
   if (oXMLReader.Attributes.First(a => a.LocalName == "r").Value == "C1")
   {
     //to do: modify the cell attributes to include t="s"
     oXMLWriter.WriteElement(new CellValue("Report Title"));
   }
}
```

How do I modify the cell attributes to include `t=s`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create an inline `Cell` with text

```
public Cell CreateInlineTextCell(string columnName, int rowIndex, string input)
{
    string cellReference = columnName + rowIndex;
    var cell = new Cell
    {
        DataType = CellValues.InlineString,
        CellReference = cellReference
    };

    var inlineString = new InlineString();
    var text = new Text { Text = input };
    inlineString.AppendChild(text);
    cell.AppendChild(inlineString);

    return cell;
}
```